# need help to code a range lookup within Lua

Tags: lua, range, lookup

I would like some assistance on how to create some coding logic within Lua. I would like to input a value for example 15500 and then with some logic for the code to know that 15 will sit within the table that has the range of 10000 - 20000 and then this will carry on with other ranges to for example 20000 - 35000.  I think maybe a tonumber function would be used,

Any assistance would be much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what's your intention.
Lua has a tonumber function called `tonumber(str)`. If you wanna check if sth is between two numbers, you can easily do this like this `if 10000 <= tonumber('15000') and tonumber('15000') <= 20000 then print(1) else print(2) end`

Comment: If your range is consistently spaced, such as ever 10000, you can do `math.floor(n / 10000)*10000` this will identify your range. Is this along the line of what you were looking for? you can also avoid the `*` by using keys like `1` for range 10000 to 19999